¿Ruta inicial no definida en flutter?
Tengo una pequeña app en flutter todo funciona bien pero hay algo que no eh podido solucionar y que me esta dando problemas. Se supone que ya eh definido estas rutas

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppRoutes {
  static const String login = '/login';
  static const String register = '/register';
  static const String home = '/home';

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    print("Ruta solicitada: ${settings.name}");
    switch (settings.name) {
      case login:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => AuthLayout(child: LoginScreen()),
        );
      case home:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => HomeLayout(child: HomeScreen()),
        );
      default:
        print("Ruta no definida: ${settings.name}");
        if (settings.name == null || settings.name == login) {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
          });
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: Text('Ruta no definida para ${settings.name}')),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}


Cuando la app esta abriendo en consola me sale
I/flutter (18062): ruta inicial: /login
I/flutter (18062): Ruta solicitada: /
I/flutter (18062): Ruta solicitada: /login

Extrañamente me sale una ruta solicitada vacia para despues pasar al login no entiendo porque ese comportamiento cuando se supone que en el main claramente se ah puesto que la ruta inicial sea el login
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';


final Logger logger = Logger(
  printer: PrettyPrinter(), 
);

/// Función para guardar errores en un archivo local
Future<void> logErrorToFile(String error, String stackTrace) async {
  try {
    // Obtener el directorio de documentos de la app
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = '${directory.path}/error_log.txt';
    final file = File(path);

    // Escribir el error en el archivo
    await file.writeAsString(
      'Error: $error\nStackTrace: $stackTrace\n\n',
      mode: FileMode.append,
    );

    // Log adicional para verificar
    logger.i("Error log saved at: $path");
  } catch (e) {
    logger.e("Error while logging to file: $e");
  }
}

Future<String> _getInitialRoute() async {
  String? token = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getToken();
  return (token != null && token.isNotEmpty) ? AppRoutes.home : AppRoutes.login;
}

/// Punto de entrada principal de la app

void main() async {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

    // Determinar la ruta inicial antes de iniciar la app
    final String initialRoute = await _getInitialRoute();
    

    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) async {
      final error = details.exceptionAsString();
      final stackTrace = details.stack.toString();

      logger.e("Flutter Error: $error\nStackTrace: ${details.stack}");
      await logErrorToFile(error, stackTrace);
    };

    runApp(
      EasyLocalization(
        supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('es', 'ES')],
        path: 'lib/assets/translations',
        fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
        child: MyApp(initialRoute: initialRoute),
      ),
    );
  }, (Object error, StackTrace stack) async {
    logger.e("Unhandled Exception: $error\nStackTrace: $stack");
    await logErrorToFile(error.toString(), stack.toString());
  });
}

/// Widget principal de la app

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialRoute;

  const MyApp({required this.initialRoute});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("ruta inicial: $initialRoute");
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
          secondary: AppColors.textColor,
        ),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyLarge: TextStyle(color: AppColors.textColor),
          bodyMedium: TextStyle(color: AppColors.textColor),
        ),
      ),
      locale: context.locale,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      
      initialRoute: initialRoute,
      onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.generateRoute,  
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

EL hecho de que al iniciar la app se detecte una ruta vacia aunque haya puesto la ruta inicial a login me esta dando problemas. ¿Por qué pasa eso? ¿En que parte esta mal?

Navigator siempre intenta buscar la ruta /, por ese motivo no es recomendable setear otra ruta como principal. Puedes obtener más información en este link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56663.
Mi recomendación es que dejes la ruta / como la principal y que sea una splash screen. Es decir, una pantalla que se muestra mientras la aplicación está haciendo la lógica necesaria para saber a qué pantalla navegar.

gracias por la info

De nada. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como la correcta si te ha servido ^^.
